# Back to the beginning of the code with several events?

Tags: c#, events, return, goto

I'm a beginner in C# and I make a quiz. My problem it is that when a question is asked that should make a loop so that the second question can be asked. I had the idea to use goto or return to turn over to the beginning but I have several events of clicks.

Here is an example:

```
private void Event1
 {
    //do something..
 }
 private void Event2
 {
    //do other things
 }
 private void Event3
 {
   //Here I want to return to the event 1 to make a loop
 }
```

Is that possible?

If no are there other solutions?

Comment: You should call it again like `Event1()` maybe.

Comment: You can call it directly: `Event1();`

Comment: I can call it in the event 3 ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Be aware you should break eventually or your program will keep running forever (until it StackOverflow's)

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that you want  to bulid 3 question in series, enable  the next options when current question is answered correctly.

If  I'm right, first of all you should enable the first button only.

When first event raised and the answer was right , disable first button, then enable next one,so on until all  questions were finished.

Comment: The questions are in one event but I have a second event to validate and test the answer, and a third event for the timer.